# Microsoft Word RTF formatting breaks after pasting in HTML and saving

Tags: email, microsoft-word, html, rtf

I have developed an HTML e-campaign which uses tables and all the ugly stuff required for HTML emails.

I'm pasting this via Open File ( I paste the URL ) and it retrieves the resources ( images ) and pastes the layout in MS Word. When I go and save this as an RTF, close Word and reopen the RTF, the images are broken.

Anyone have a clue as to how to work around this issue? I can confirm 100% that the image resource is VALID, it's through `http` and NOT `https`.

I've tried various advanced options relating to tables/formatting and all to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

When you're selecting the image file, you'll notice there's a drop down button next to the Insert button.  Click on that and choose *Link to File* instead.  That should work better.

[image: Word insert]

Unfortunately, Microsoft Word doesn't handle images in RTF format very well, nor does it handle HTML very well, especially for your purposes.  You might still have trouble.  Consider using a [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) HTML editor instead, such as [KompoZer](http://kompozer.net/) (which is free), [Microsoft Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Web_Overview.aspx) or [Adobe Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver/) (which are not).  They won't mangle your links and produce cleaner HTML output that will work better in many e-mail clients.